# Question about subsets of Independent random variables and events

Tags: probability, independence

Definition for independent random variables:

The countably valued random variables $X1,...,X_n$ are said to be independent iff for numbers $x_1,...x_n,$ we have
$$P(X_1=x_1,...,X_n=x_n)=P(X_1=x_1)...P(X_n=x_n)$$

Deduce further by replacing single values $x_i$ by arbitrary sets $S_i$:

For arbitrary countable sets $S_1,...S_n:$
$$P(X_1\in S_1,...,X_n\in S_n)=P(X_1\in S_1)...P(X_n\in S_n)$$

Definition for independent events:

the n events $A_1,A_2,...,A_n$ are independent if the intersection of any subset of them has its probabilities of the individual events.

For any subset$(i_1,i_2,...,i_k) \text{ of } (1,2,...,n):$
$$P(A_{i_1}∩A_{i_2}∩...∩A_{i_k})=P(A_{i_1})P(A_{i_2})...P(A_{i_n})$$

my question:
For indenpent random variables, does the property still apply on any of the subsets? if not provide an example.

Comment: Yes it still holds

Answer (score 1):

> For independent random variables, does the property still apply on any of the subsets?

Yes.  Just let $A_i$ be the *event* that $X_i\in S_i$.  Any countable set of such events— ${\{X_i\in S_i\}}_{i=1}^n$ for any collection of arbitrary set of values ${\{S_i\}}_{i=1}^n$ —shall be mutually independent exactly when the corresponding indexed set of random variables– ${\{X_i\}}_{i=1}^n$ –are mutually independent.